# Why am I unable to save my output to a file from a command that takes input as the file itself?

Tags: text-processing, io-redirection, command

For example, here's my command I'm using:

```
tr -d '\n' < newfile.ppm
```

I want to output the results to that exact same file, so I am now doing:

```
tr -d '\n' < newfile.ppm > newfile.ppm
```

Why is this not working and how can I get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an extremely common "gotcha".

When you redirect stdout or stderr to write to a file, the shell will first truncate the file to prepare it for writing. So what's occurring is roughly the following:

1. Your shell sets stdin to `newfile.ppm`
2. Your shell truncates `newfile.ppm` to length 0
3. Your shell sets stdout to `newfile.ppm`
4. Your shell runs `tr -d '\n'`. As you can see, at this point, the contents of `newfile.ppm` are already gone, so there is nothing to read.

To work around this, just output to another file instead. You can then rename it afterwards

Answer (score -1):

This'll do the job you want.

```
[stephan@stephan] ~ 
$ echo "meh                                    
" > file
[stephan@stephan] ~ 
$ cat file | tr -d '\n' > file ; cat file 
meh
```

Comment: I just tried it, but doing so results in the whole file being erased

Comment: I tweaked what I wrote to match your question more closely.

Comment: Here is the command I had inputted: cat newfile.ppm | tr -d '\n' > newfile.ppm

Comment: Not sure what's different on your system, this would definitely work though: `cat file | tr -d '\n' > newfile ; mv newfile file`

Comment: Additionally, this post explains in much greater detail about why your initial approach doesn't work: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators

Comment: That link is useful, but when I tried this: tr -d '\n' < newfile.ppm >| bignewfile.txt
it works

Comment: tr -d '\n' < newfile.ppm >| newfile.ppm however doesn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: Scroll down the link I posted, under "Warning regarding '>'" - Redirection of output causes the file … to be opened for writing ….  If the file does not exist it is created; if it does exist it is truncated to zero size.